# Nitrous.IO and Django non-rel

Tags: python, django, nitrousio

Is it possible to use [Django non-rel](http://django-nonrel.org/) with a Nitrous.IO box without using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)?

Using virtualenv, I can setup the version and apps needed to run Django non-rel. But Is there a better way?

I have a "bran" box with Django stack, and looking in [Autoparts](https://github.com/action-io/autoparts), there doesn't seem to be any Django packages listed. Let alone non-rel.

Note: Asked during [Nitrous.IO](https://www.nitrous.io) Beta